# JS - Return a string from find helper

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

How can you return a string from the find helper rather than its matched value? "Found it" does not render out

```
var ladders = [
    { id: 1, height: 20 },
    { id: 3, height: 25 }
]

function findWhere(array, criteria) {
    return array.find(function(item) {
        if( (item[Object.keys(criteria)]) == Object.values(criteria) ) {
            return "Found it"
        }
    });
}

console.log(findWhere(ladders, {height: '20'}));
```

Comment: Could it be a type mismatch? String vs Integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Array.some()` to return a Boolean value, and decide what string to present according to the value:

```js
const ladders = [{ id: 1, height: 20 }, { id: 3, height: 25 }]

const findWhere = (array, [key, value]) => 
  array.some(item => item[key] === value)
  
const result = findWhere(ladders, ['height', 25]) ? 'found' : 'not found'

console.log(result)
```

Or you can use `Object.entries()` if you want to use a predicate object:

```js
const ladders = [{ id: 1, height: 20 }, { id: 3, height: 25 }]

const findWhere = (array, predicate) => {
  const [key, value] = Object.entries(predicate)[0]
  
  return array.some(item => item[key] === value)
};
  
const result = findWhere(ladders, { height: 25 }) ? 'found' : 'not found'

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't, `find` returns the first value which matched (returned a truthy value).

In your example, whenever the correct element is matched, `"Found it"` string is being returned. Because that's a truthy value, returning it signals the `find` method that whatever the value the string was returned on was the sought-after one.

To make `findWhere` work as desired though, you could implement it as follows:

```js
var arr = [{height: 10}, {height: 2}, {height: 7}];

function findWhere(array, criteria) {
    var itemFound = array.find(function(item) {
        return item.height == criteria;
    });
    
    return itemFound ? "Found it" : "Not Found";
}

console.log(findWhere(arr, 7)); // Found it
console.log(findWhere(arr, -99)) // Not Found
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var ladders = [
    { id: 1, height: 20 },
    { id: 3, height: 25 }
]

function findWhere(array, criteria) {
    var itemFound = array.find(function(item) {
        return item.height == criteria;
    });
    return itemFound !== undefined ? "Found it" : "Not Found";
}

console.log(findWhere(ladders, {height: '20'}.height));
console.log(findWhere(ladders, {height: '22'}.height));
```

Note `return item.height == criteria;` uses double equals instead of triple equals, since types doesn't match

Answer (score 1):

Here is a generic method that will successfully find your and return your criteria (as long as all elements are at maximum one object deep)

```js
var ladders = [
    { id: 1, height: 20 },
    { id: 3, height: 25 }
]

function findWhere(arr, criteria) {
    const toFind = Object.entries(criteria);
    const res = arr.find(item=>{
      return toFind.every(([key, value])=>item[key] == value);
    });
    return res ? "Found it" : "Didn't find it";
}

console.log(findWhere(ladders, {height: '20'}));
console.log(findWhere(ladders, {height: '20', id: 1}));
console.log(findWhere(ladders, {id: 3}));
console.log(findWhere(ladders, {height: 25}));
```

Comment: unless i don't pass `console.log(findWhere(ladders, {}));`, anyways +1